# Why do "selectedCountry", "selectedAge", "selectedGender" return null?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

When I run my app and go to the "EditProfile" activity. And then, I will immediately receive the toast message "Something is wrong" which means, the variables "selectedCountry", "selectedAge", and "selectedGender" are null.

```
 public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

UserInfo userInfo;
UserInfo profileDetails;
Spinner spinnerFrom;
Spinner spinnerAge;
Spinner spinnerGender;
EditText hobbyEdit;
Button btnDone;
TextView textView;
String selectedCountry;
String selectedAge;
String selectedGender;

DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this, "MyUsers", null, 5);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", userInfo.getId());
            intent.putExtra("username", userInfo.getUsername());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int id = extras.getInt("id");
    final String username = extras.getString("username");


    // Username
    userInfo = new UserInfo(id, username);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernameUnedit);
    textView.setText(username);



    // Country
    spinnerFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrom);
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    final ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
    countries.add("-");
    for (Locale locale : locales) {
        String country = locale.getDisplayCountry();
        if (country.trim().length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country)) {
            countries.add(country);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(countries);

    ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);

    countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerFrom.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
    spinnerFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedCountry = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



    // Age
    spinnerAge = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAge);
    final ArrayList<String> ages = new ArrayList<String>();
    ages.add("-");
    for (int i = 18; i < 100; i++) {
        ages.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> ageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ages);
    ageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerAge.setAdapter(ageAdapter);
    spinnerAge.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedAge = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



    // Gender
    spinnerGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGender);
    final ArrayList<String> genders = new ArrayList<String>();
    genders.add("-");
    genders.add("Male ♂");
    genders.add("Female ♀");
    genders.add("Other");

    ArrayAdapter<String> genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, genders);
    genderAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerGender.setAdapter(genderAdapter);
    spinnerGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedGender = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



    // Hobby
    hobbyEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hobbyEdit);



    // Button done
    btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
    btnDone.setEnabled(false);

/* Stuck at this if statement below */
    if (selectedCountry != null && selectedAge != null && selectedGender != null) {
        if (!mydb.isStoredProfileDetails(username, selectedCountry, selectedAge, selectedGender, hobbyEdit.getText().toString())) {
            btnDone.setEnabled(true);
            btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    profileDetails = new UserInfo(selectedCountry, selectedAge, selectedGender, hobbyEdit.getText().toString());
                    mydb.updateTable(username, profileDetails);

                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something is wrong 2.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something is wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

I expect that after choosing an item from those 3 dropdown lists (spinners) and the values of the chosen items do not exist in database, then the "Done" button would be clickable. Once the button is clicked, it would store the selected values from the dropdown lists (spinners) into database by updating it.

Unfortunately, I am stuck at the if statement as stated in the given code as it keeps returning the "else" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Set your variable as...

```
String selectedCountry = "";
String selectedAge = "";
String selectedGender = "";
```

And check condition as...

```
if (!selectedCountry.equals("") && !selectedAge.equals("") && !selectedGender.equals("")) {
//your code goes here
}
```

Comment: It returns the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your both conditions in Spinner's `OnItemSelectedListener`, If both conditions will return true then enable your button. and call setonClickListener on button in onCreateView, like this.

```
 spinnerGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedGender = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //Conditions to enable button
            if (selectedCountry != null && selectedAge != null && selectedGender != null) {
            if (!mydb.isStoredProfileDetails(username, selectedCountry, selectedAge, selectedGender, hobbyEdit.getText().toString())) {
                btnDone.setEnabled(true);
            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

add these lines in all spinners.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` method, you have instantiated the views and attached listeners to them. That is perfectly fine. However, this does not mean that the logic in those listeners will be execute at the same time and order. You have just defined the behaviour of the listeners. After all that initialisation, your code directly checks the values of the three Strings mentioned in your question. It does not wait for a user to interact with the spinners.

What you want is to trigger the change in the "done" button when a user selects something from the spinner. So the logic of setting the strings and thereby checking if you could enable the "done" button must go in the listeners of the spinners.

I am not giving you a direct code solution to the problem, but an approach which you could employ.